# Python scraping with pandas query

Tags: python, pandas

I want to scrape the coin names from this website (https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/recently_added?page=1)

I have come up with this to do it:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import time

url1 = "https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/recently_added?page=1"
df = pd.read_html(requests.get(url1).text, flavor="bs4")
df = pd.concat(df).drop(["Unnamed: 0"], axis=1)
df1=df['Coin']
print(df1)
```

The code prints this:

```
0              Corgi Inu  CORGI  CORGI
1                  Bistroo  BIST  BIST
2                 FireBall  FIRE  FIRE
3             Neko Network  NEKO  NEKO
4              LatteSwap  LATTE  LATTE
                ...
```

I want to only select the names that appear in the first column, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.str.rsplit`:

```py
names = df["Coin"].str.rsplit(n=2).str[0]
print(names)
```

Prints:

```
0                    Corgi Inu
1                      Bistroo
2                     FireBall
3                 Neko Network
4                    LatteSwap
5                      Voltbit
6                    Paddycoin
7                 Bezoge Earth
8                Anonymous BSC

...and so on.
```

---

If you want it in a list form:

```py
print(names.tolist())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split each row and grab what you need with a **list comprehension** :

```
# the [:-2] will omit the last two "columns"
coin_names = [" ".join(s.split()[:-2]) for s in list(df1)]
```